# Error NU1605 Detected package downgrade: log4net from 2.0.11 to 2.0.3

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise version 15.9.27 and .NET Framework 4.5.

I just installed Windows 10 Update version 10.0.18363 build 18363.

I can compile all other projects in the Solution, but one of the project have yellow triangles on all the Dependencies (Assemblies and Nuget), including System, System.Core, System.Data.

When I tried to compile that one project, I am getting this error

```
Error   NU1605  Detected package downgrade: log4net from 2.0.11 to 2.0.3. 
Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
```

When I tried to install log4net 2.0.11 thru Nuget Package Manager, I am getting this error

```
Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for '....'.
```

I have "Clear All NuGet Cache(s)"
The other projects have log4net 2.0.11

How can I fix this problem ?
Thank you

Comment: enter `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run`-->set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Detailed` to get the detailed build log. And then try your downgrade step again to find what happens. Or you could disable any other package sources and remain only one package source `nuget.org`. Like this: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/40DMc.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40DMc.png).

Comment: I set the MSBuild project build output verbosity to Detailed and the only package sources I use is nuget.org. This is from the error log:
Restore failed in 44.86 ms for C:\myproject.csproj. NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors. ......This is in the Error list: "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'myproject'.

Comment: Guess one: I think you should check other nuget packages on your current project and maybe there is a nuget package that depends >`log4net 2.0.3` so that you cannot downgrade it. Besides, if your situation is not that, you should run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Packager Manager`-->`Package Manager Console` to reinstall all nuget packages to check it.

Comment: Besides log4net 2.0.3, the project uses Nuget Autofac 3.5.2 and EntityFramework 6.1.3. How can I find out if Autofac 3.5.2 and EntityFramework 6.1.3 depends on log4net > version 2.0.3 ? My solution contains a few projects. Do all the projects need to use the same version of log4net ie, all of them uses log4net 2.03, or all of them uses log4net 2.0.11 ?

Comment: I checked your nuget package and it seems that they do not depend on `log4net `. Quite strange. Close VS, delete nuget.config under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and then  delete .vs hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. Then, restart your project to test again.

Comment: I deleted nuget.config, .vs, bin and obj folders. Brought up the solution in VS, and added the "http_proxy" entry to nuget.config. When I build the project, I am still getting "Error NU1605 Detected package downgrade: log4net from 2.0.11 to 2.0.3..ProjWBuildErr -> AnotherProjInThisSln -> log4net (>= 2.0.11) ProjWBuildErr -> log4net (>= 2.0.3)". The other projects in this solution compiled with log4net 2.0.11. Trying to install log4net 2.0.11 in ProjWBuildError thru Nuget Package Manager, I am still getting the error "Error Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for '....'